# caption shortcode using image alt as caption

Tags: shortcode, captions

[image]

The img alt attribute is dsplaying as caption and laos the caption is displaying, I do not  want to display the img alt attribute as caption , how can I remove it.

### my code

```
 <p>
    [caption id="attachment_2103" align="alignnone" width="200"]
<a href="http://realwaymedia.info/aiwa-stage2/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/pid_24063.jpg">
<img class="wp-image-2103 size-medium" alt="Book Cover image" src="http://realwaymedia.info/aiwa-stage2/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/pid_24063-200x300.jpg"  width="200" height="300" /></a>
This is a caption[/caption]</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove caption text, you can override the caption short-code using below code:

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );

function my_img_caption_shortcode( $empty, $attr, $content ){
    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'      => '',
        'align'   => 'alignnone',
        'width'   => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr );

    if ( 1 > (int) $attr['width'] || empty( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( $attr['id'] ) {
        $attr['id'] = 'id="' . esc_attr( $attr['id'] ) . '" ';
    }

    return '<div ' . $attr['id']
    . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr( $attr['align'] ) . '" '
    . 'style="max-width: ' . ( 10 + (int) $attr['width'] ) . 'px;">'
    . do_shortcode( $content )
    . '</div>';

}
```

For more details, refer [CODEX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/img_caption_shortcode)

**UPDATE:**

Try changing below mentioned line.

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 999, 3 );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems it is already overridden , It is not showing the default behavior, as per codex, It should not display the image alt attribute , when the image is displaying .but in my case as the image shows, it can be seen.

Comment: The code you have post is from wp-include/media.php file, I am on that page, but we should not override this, It seems there is some other problem.

Comment: Try UPDATE code of my answer. Also the answer posted is not same as codex, it's a bit modified.

Comment: It seems my question is little bit unclear to you, still your answer is helpful. As it will be a workaround, if I will be unable to solve it.It deserves an upvote.

Comment: The client was using another plugin name "Velvet Blues Image Captions" to display alt as caption :P